# How to define special language for variable in model in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to set special language for input box in model box?

Actually I want a input box just accept English language, nothing else. To describe more: as I have `number` as `integer` in my following code, I want `username` as just English language and number.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password', 'name'], 'required'],
            [['number'], 'integer'], 
            [['username'],  'language' => 'en-US',], //I want username accept just English language
        ];
    }
```

Is there something for define language in model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "match" validator

```
['username', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i']
```

Comment: I want in the textbox automatically change to english langualge from anther language.

Comment: and off course I want input box to be able to enter number too.

Comment: is it possible to change automatically language in input focus by yii? or it has to be by javascript?

Comment: Please explain on that are you mean "change to english".
If validation, use the "match" validator.
If transliteration use `yii\helpers\Inflector::transliterate()`.
If the application language, use `Yii::$app->language`

Comment: let me explain more. my default language in my web site is **Persian**. now I want when focus on username inputbox, language change to **English** automatically

Comment: other inputboxes are persian.

Comment: I want change keyboard language automatically

Comment: As I understand, you need to change the keyboard layout. This is inpossible to do by PHP, use Javascript

Comment: Ok. thanks a lot for you help. just add number in your validation in your answer too.

Comment: I need number in `pattern` too.